# Replace web page picture with another keeping the same file name

Tags: javascript

As you will see I am by no means a programmer and this is my first dabble.

I am trying to get a program called Actiontiles to display a media tile (a html link to a picture on a web page). I want the image to show what bin I need to take out that week for collection.

I have managed to cobble together a javascript to display one of 4 bin images depending upon the date, which although messy is a set of `if` statements and seems to do the job, I thought I'd cracked it, simply host it and point Actiontiles to the web page.

The problem is the Actiontile link requires the link to the picture on the web page, so I need to change the picture based upon the date without altering the filename, somehow renaming one of my 4 images to the picture file name that is linked.

Is there a simple way that I can do this?

```
<script language="javascript">
    <!-- ©2019 Paul
    <!-- Bin Collection

    var pic='';
    mytime=new Date();
    mymonth=mytime.getMonth()+1;
    mydate=mytime.getDate();

    if (mymonth==3 && (mydate>=5 && mydate<=11)){pic="<img src=/images/box.png width=300 height=300 alt=Recycling Boxes Collection>";
    }
    else if (mymonth==3 && (mydate>=12 && mydate<18)){pic="<img src=/images/blackbin.png width=300 height=300 alt=General Waste Black Bin Collection>";
    }
    else {
    pic="<img src=/images/default.png width=300 height=300 alt=default>"
    }

    document.write(pic);
    //-->
</script>
```

Comment: No, you can't do that with javascript, also, if you somehow manage to change the image name, you need to reload the html page to update the changes.

Comment: Thanks, I can deal with the reload, Actiontiles is able to specify a refresh/reload interval.

Comment: "somehow renaming one of my 4 images to the picture file name that is linked"

Linked where? Where do you wanna get the pictures from? You didn´t say. But sure enough you can change the pictures src with javascript.

Comment: Linked in Actiontiles that points to a specific image, if I right click the image on any web page and 'copy image address', I can paste this in Actiontiles, I need to copy one of the 4 images stored in say my images folder over the linked image so that the filename stays the same.

Comment: So am I getting this right you want to select one of 4 images (but those 4 images are always the same 4 images and not dynamic). And depending on the day you want one of the images to be copied to some directory on your server. If so then you can´t do that with javascript running in browsers. You need node or something that has access to your servers file system.

Comment: yep, sounds like you have the gist, thanks Max for your help, I'll investigate node. I thought it would be a simple renaming exercise, but as you suggest I am playing with the file system.